# Setting lock screen in Windows Phone 8 with a non local image

Tags: windows-phone, lockscreen, windows-phone-8

I am trying to set the lock screen on a Windows Phone 8 using the SetImageUri, but I can't get it to work with a non local image.  In my case I have images in a separate assembly, and on a remote server (Azure CDN).

I have already added the manifest entry, and gotten the user permission to be a provider from the sample code.

This is what the code looks like the imageUri would be something like this:

https://infinitecodex.blob.core.windows.net/nflfanapps/26-WALL-1.png

The image exits and is a valid file.  I tried putting it in a separate images assembly, and still get this error.

```
                // At this stage, the app is the active lock screen background provider.
                var uri = new Uri(imageUri, UriKind.Absolute);

                // Set the lock screen background image.
                Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);
```

Everything I try results in an exception:

```
    Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You've only been here four years, so you might not have noticed that tags stand alone.  That is, combining `windows` and `phone` doesn't mean you're talking about the product known as Windows Phone.  Please be sure to select your tags with care.  :)

Comment: Doesn't mean it makes sense... :)  "windows phone" is how I would tag it in almost every other system I work with, so that is more natural to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this guide you can only use images stored in your Isolated Storage or images packaged with your app:
[Lock screen background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
Nothing stops you from downloading the image to isolated storage and using the Uri to this image as the lockscreen source.

> // At this stage, the app is the active lock screen background
>   provider.// The following code example shows the new URI schema.//
>   ms-appdata points to the root of the local app data folder.// ms-appx
>   points to the Local app install folder, to reference resources bundled
>   in the XAP package.var schema = isAppResource ? "ms-appx:///" :
>   "ms-appdata:///Local/";

Answer (score 1):

I guess only isolated storage image can be used as locked image

Answer (score 0):

Also see MSDN doc on SetImageUri;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.system.userprofile.lockscreen.setimageuri(v=vs.105).aspx
"*An absolute path Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) to the image in **isolated storage, or the image install path**."*